# Can't make call to server using Windows Phone background task

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Background task for Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1, and it works fine as long as I don't need to access the internet.

Below is the code I attempt to run:

```
var query = from photoTest2 in ParseObject.GetQuery("PhotoTest2")
                        where photoTest2.Get<string>("username") != "x"
                        select photoTest2;
            int resultsCount = await query.OrderByDescending("createdAt").WhereWithinDistance("location", point, ParseGeoDistance.FromKilometers(10)).CountAsync();
```

This method runs fine when I just use a standard method and display the "resultCount" in a MessageBox, and takes less than a second. However, as a background task it just stalls indefinitely.

This is the code for the Background Task:

```
public sealed class FirstTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        int resultsCount;

        public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            DateTime timeNow = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan minus28 = new TimeSpan(0, 28, 0);
            DateTime timeGone = timeNow.Subtract(minus28);

            BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
            await GetCount();
            deferral.Complete();

            ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastText02;
            XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);
            XmlNodeList textElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
            textElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("New Pictures!"));
            textElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(resultsCount + " new images in your area"));
            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(new ToastNotification(toastXml));


        }

        private async Task GetCount()
        {
            var point = new ParseGeoPoint(11.11, -11.11);
            var distance = new ParseGeoDistance(360);

            var query = from photoTest2 in ParseObject.GetQuery("PhotoTest2")
                        where photoTest2.Get<string>("username") != "x"
                        select photoTest2;
            resultsCount = await query.OrderByDescending("createdAt").WhereWithinDistance("location", point, ParseGeoDistance.FromKilometers(10)).CountAsync();

        }
```

Help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Where is ParseObject defined?  The backgroundworker need an instance of ParseObject.  Backgroundworker is a separate process from main program and needs the parameters/object passed into the process.

Comment: It is defined just within that class. Should it defined somewhere else? Surely it simply wouldn't compile if it weren't defined correctly? :)

Comment: I think there is some dependency outside the class.  No sure.  Usually object defined outside a backgroundworker needs to be passed as an instance to the backgroundworkers as a state object when starting the backgroundworker.

Comment: Where exactly would I put this, and/or how would I do it? For what it's worth I've tried doing a HTTP client request too instead of the Parse request, and it just stops at the "await" section too.

Comment: There are two examples on following webpage.  See 2nd example : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx